# Guess what’s in here? Cake! Why there is no "a" article?

Tags: grammar

Why does she say, "it’s cake," (instead of, "it’s a cake," or, "it’s the cake")? Why does she talk like a foreigner?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joUlxij0e8E&t=4m00s

Comment: Welcome to ELL. :) It's an interesting question. However, I think she talks perfectly like a native speaker in that video. Hmm... Why do you think that she talks like a foreigner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain things that could be put in a box, and it would sound odd if I ***didn't*** use an article. For example:

> *Guess what's in this box?*
>   **It's puppy!** *
>   **It's sewing machine!** *
>   **It's vacuum cleaner!** *
>   <sub>(The * character denotes an error. These should be "It's **a** puppy," "It's **a** sewing machine," "It's **a** vacuum cleaner.")</sub>

However, if there was more than one of something in a box, and the noun was pluralized, no article would be needed:

> *Guess what's in this carton?*
>   **It's puppies!**
>   **It's sewing machines!**
>   **It's vacuum cleaners!**

From a grammatical perspective, some nouns can function as *mass nouns*, meaning that these words can function as a plural, even when written in the singular. Therefore, no article would be needed:

> *Guess what's in this crate?*
>   **It's rice!**
>   **It's beer!**
>   **It's fish!**

One way to tell if a word can function as a mass noun is to try to use *some* in front of the singular form, where *some* means "an unspecified amount of". This won't work if the noun can't be used as a mass noun:

> *What would you like for your birthday?*
>   **I'm hoping for some candy.
>
>   I'm hoping for some coffee.
>
>   I'm hoping for some cake.
>
>   I'm hoping for some clock.**<sup>⁎</sup>

"I'm hoping for some clock," would be grammatical if the person means, "I'm hoping for a clock of some kind," but ***not*** if the person means, "I'm hoping for some unspecified amount of clock."

Because *cake* can indeed function as a mass noun, the sentence in the video sounds like one that would be uttered by a competent native speaker. No article is needed (although one could be used – there would be nothing wrong with, "It's a cake!").